# AddPaging(...) Error - React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am getting the following error when I run my app:

[image]

I am using IOS, There are no error when I run my app. I would like to know how to fix this.

Comment: It looks like you may have returned undefined, an array, or some other invalid object from your `AddPaging` component. I assume you're using [this](https://github.com/rreusser/react-native-paged-scroll-view)? Maybe you can start trying to verify that is actually returning something?

Comment: How would I go about checking that?

Comment: Do you have any code of you using the `AddPaging` component? Is there a `render` function?

Comment: No that is referencing something inside of the module.